# How to put OR condition with until loop in Ansible

Tags: tomcat, ansible

I am writing a script for automation deployment and I have come across a weird scenario.

When i stop tomcat using command `svcadm disable tomcat` it can go to 2 states - `maintenence` OR `disabled`. When it goes into `disabled` state then it means tomcat has been stopped gracefully but when it goes into `maintenence` state it means it hasn't been stopped properly and I have to run the `svcadm disable tomcat` again to make it in `disabled` state.

Below is my playbook `main.yml` for role stopping tomcat - Here 1st I am stopping the tomcat so when the first task occurs, it gracefully starts stopping but remains in `online` state for some time (few seconds). So I am trying to check the status of tomcat using `svcs tomcat` whether it's in `disabled` state OR `maintenence` state. The OR condition with `until` is not working here.

```
- name: Stopping tomcat Service on remote host
   shell: "svcadm disable tomcat"
   ignore_errors: true

 - name: Verifying tomcat service status to make sure it is in disabled state.
   shell: "svcs tomcat"
   register: result
   until: result.stdout_lines.1.split().0 == "disabled" or result.stdout_lines.1.split().0 == "maintenance"
   retries: 10
   delay: 10

 - shell: "svcadm disable tomcat"
   when: (tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0) == "maintenance"
```

I am not sure if it is the correct approach here but is there any other better way to achieve this task?
The thing is after running the `scvadm disable tomcat` command, tomcat could be in any of the 3 states - `online` OR `maintenence` OR `disabled`.
I can't process further until my tomcat goes into `disabled` mode.

Let me know if anyone can advice on this please.

Comment: Regarding your exact question, a cleaner way would be `until: result.stdout_lines.1.split().0 in ["disabled, "maintenance"]`. Now doing this via shell is not really the best ansible way. You should use the [`service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) to enable/disable and [`service_facts` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html) to check for status.

Comment: You could use the wait_for module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameters and check if the tomcat-port is closed

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for your response. I know about service module but I am bind to use the ```svcadm``` command to enable/disable tomcats. We have been asked specifically to use this

Comment: `service` uses the underlying init system, including Solaris SMF when relevant. Are your saying that you've specifically been asked not to use ansible to manage your service ? Because all it will do in your case is run svcadm (unless I totally miss the point...)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html
by setting `enabled: no` which disables the tomcat service

Answer (score 0):

something link that ?

```yml
- shell: "svcadm disable tomcat"
   when: (tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0) == "maintenance" or
         (tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0) == "disabled"
         (tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0) == "online"
```